# How to return each word and its respective length from a list

Tags: python, string, list, split, mapping

I am trying to find the length of all the words in a string and return a list with each word and its lengths next to it. Here is an example:

> A string of "hello python" would return ["hello 5", "python 6"]

I have written this so far:

```
ele1 = str_[0]
lettlist = list(map(len, str_.split()))
return (str(lettlist))
```

And it returns just the numbers e.g., '[5, 5]' for "hello world". How do I get it to return both string and numbers in the list like my example above?

Comment: "And it returns just the numbers e.g., '[5, 5]' for "hello world"." - well, yes, because the `len` function that is being `map`ped only gives back those values. Can you write a function that gives you the desired result for one string? What happens if you try `map`ping that function intead of `len`? What part are you actually stuck with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to create the list, and string formatting to create values.

Since you need to word in the result, you can create a fstring with the word and compute the length of the word and add the value in the same string. Python will format the result string into the result you want, and iterate over the list that `phrase.split()` return. When every value is computed, it create the final list.

```py
def word_lengths(phrase):
    return [f"{word} {len(word)}" for word in phrase.split()]

print(word_lengths("How long are the words in this phrase"))
# ['How 3', 'long 4', 'are 3', 'the 3', 'words 5', 'in 2', 'this 4', 'phrase 6']
```

`map` is not a very practical tool when you want to do manipulation like this. It's often easier to use list comprehension because the syntax is easier to get, adapt and fix if it doesn't do what you want.

Using the `map` function, here is the code:

```py
def word_lengths(phrase):
    return list(map(lambda word: f"{word} {len(word)}", phrase.split()))
```

As you can see, it's less "english" that a list comprehension, and need a cast into list.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but I don't really see why a "list comprehension" would be better (or easier to understand) than a call to map(). Both are concise ways of writing a "for each loop" (just "for loop" in Python parlance) over a collection, doing something with each element, and returning another collection. One way is embedded into the language and the other uses a separate function (but it's also part of the core Python specification). For old school programmers, a classic loop may look even "more english". In the end, I think, is just a matter of preference.

Comment: Because it's more pythonic. The convention recommand using a list comprehension in this case, because it tend to be easier to explain to beginner and old-school programmer won't struggle either, where map can be difficult to grasp to people not used to the concept of function being first class object.

Comment: Is it? Python has 70 core functions, including constructors like int(). Not a big count by today standards; and map() is one of these functions. It's also a modern one, returning an iterator and yielding the results. Functions as FCO may be a difficult concept for Java programmers, but not really for others. I'm 100% into embracing the philosophy of a language (that's why I don't like TypeScript or Rust). But programmers should use available tools in creative (and racional) ways, instead of just repeating formulas. Lauren was using a map(), and trying to understand what was wrong with it.

Comment: That's why I showed the solution with map. Also, since the OP struggle with map and how to use it, I suggested a simpler tool. And from experience, list comprehension is easier to understand than map. That's all and if you don't like my advice to the OP, ok, noticed. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the most of your code (and avoiding the creation of a named function), you could just do:

```
str_ = "hello world"
lettlist = list(map(lambda s : s + " " + str(len(s)), str_.split()))
return str(lettlist)
```

Please note that I just replaced the function (or function reference) supplied, as the first parameter, to map().

```
len
```

is replaced by:

```
lambda s : s + " " + str(len(s))
```